# How do I reverse a sentence in python?

Tags: python, reverse, sentence

I've been searching for a way to reverse sentences, but I can't seem to find one.  I was hoping to find a way in Python; however, I'm not sure if there is a way to do it.  If anybody knows of a way to do it, I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Please give an example of reversing a sentence.

Comment: did you try to code it?

Comment: this is a basic job interview question.

Comment: @catbadger I hope the expected answer is "Define sentence. Define reverse."

Comment: By reverse I meant like taking "How are you?" and making it "?uoy era woH"

Comment: @timgeb I think the correct thing to do with this question is not answer it, but flag as "very low quality"

Comment: @catbadger Flags shouldn't be used for that. We don't need to waste mod's time on posts like this. That's also not a valid flag for a question anyways afaik. Just downvote it.

Comment: You're "not sure" if Python has a way to do a very basic and common string manipulation? Indeed, it does.  `forward = "How are you?" ; drawkcab = forward[::-1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would reverse "the quick brown fox" to "xof nworb kciuq eht". Is that what you mean?

```
str1 = "the quick brown fox"
str2 = ""

for i in range(len(str1)):
    str2 += str1[(len(str1)-i)-1]

print(str2)
```

Comment: Yeah! This is what I was meaning.  Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Reversing the string is quite easy:
just add the index to the end of each value:

```
q = 'qwerty'
k = ''
for i in q:
    k = i+k
print(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way off the top of my head, but there may be a more efficient way.

```
a = "this is a sentence"
b = "".join([a[i] for i in reversed(range(len(a)))])
```

b should now contain 'ecnetnes a si siht'

Comment: Awesome, thanks dude!